# swift generic sequence with identifiable constraint on elements

Tags: swift

seems like it should be really easy - but I can't find any way of constraining a generic on a sequence of items to a particular item type - in this case - I want to say that I can work with any sequence, as long as the items making up the sequence are all Identifiable

```swift
     // none of these compile
     //
     struct GridView<List>  : View where List: Sequence, List.Type : Identifiable
     struct GridView<List, Item> : View where List: Sequence, Item: Identifiable, List.Type == Item
     struct GridView<List, Item>  : View where List: Sequence, Item: Identifiable, List.Type : Item
```

Is there any way to do it?   At the moment I can get by by just having a generic type "Item" - and taking [Item] - but ideally I'd like to work with any sequence - not force it to be a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is almost correct. To refer to the element type of a `Sequence`, use [`.Element`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2908099-element), not `.Type`. `.Type` refers to the [metatype](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID455) of a type.

```
struct GridView<ListType>: View where ListType: Sequence, ListType.Element: Identifiable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct GridView<List: Sequence>: View where List.Element: Identifiable {
  // ...
}
```

`Sequence` defines an associated type called `Element`, which you can constrain to conform to `Identifiable`